# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, preg-match

I get this error on my site and i dont know why:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be
>   alphanumeric or backslash

The error is in this function:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) AND preg_match("\.\.", $_REQUEST['page'])) {
Header("Location: index.php");
die();
```

}

Comment: Already answered below, but I wanted to add that strpos should be quicker than any preg_match, especially if you've not already used a preg function in this request.  `(strpos($_REQUEST['page'], '..') !== false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enclose the regular expression in [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) AND preg_match("/\.\./", $_REQUEST['page'])) {
     Header("Location: index.php");
     die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked! :) But I have one more question. What about this one?
`  $msg = preg_match("(http|https|ftp|gopher|news)://([$ACCEPT_CHARS]+)", "<a href=\"\\1://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\1://\\2</a>", $msg);`

Comment: You have to escape the forward slashes by prepending backslashes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an interesting requirement when supplying a pattern for a regex operation (such as preg_match), that [the pattern needs to have a character delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) at the start and end of the string. This can be any character, but should not be used in the pattern. For example, you may use the hash symbol as your delimiter:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) AND preg_match("#\.\.#", $_REQUEST['page'])) {
```